# Sailsjs - sails lift command is not working on windows

Tags: sails.js

I'm new to sailsjs. I created a new simple application with sailsjs and after run `sails lift` I got following error. Could you please anyone have an idea about this issue and tell how fix this.

Thanks.

```
info: Starting app...


C:\Users\kavi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\errors\warn.js:48
      'The local Sails dependency installed at `' + pathTo.localSails + '` ' +
                                                    ^
ReferenceError: pathTo is not defined
    at Object.module.exports.badLocalDependency (C:\Users\kavi\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\sails\errors\warn.js:48:53)
    at Sails.isLocalSailsValid (C:\Users\kavi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\s
ails\lib\app\private\isLocalSailsValid.js:51:14)
    at Function.bound [as isLocalSailsValid] (C:\Users\kavi\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\sails\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:729:21)
    at Command.module.exports (C:\Users\kavi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sa
ils\bin\sails-lift.js:48:13)
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kavi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails
\node_modules\commander\index.js:249:8)
    at Command.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\kavi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\n
ode_modules\commander\index.js:477:12)
    at Command.parse (C:\Users\kavi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_
modules\commander\index.js:370:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kavi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\
bin\sails.js:144:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Comment: Did you set the path for sailsjs ?

Comment: try running ```npm install``` in your project root folder, and after ```sails lift```. Is still with error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run `npm install` in your project root folder and after `sails lift`.

Comment: Also if you still have the same issue with a current project, try to delete the node_modules folder and run npm install again.

Answer (score 3):

follow these steps,

1: `npm install sails -g`

2: `npm install`

note-run these commands as administrator